# libapache2-mod-ruid2 broken in combination with http2

Tags: apache2, php

I am having the same issue in ubuntu 16.04. When i enable libapache2-mod-ruid2 i get the following error in my apache error log:

```
[Tue May 31 10:53:07.681923 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7534] AH00051: child pid 14349 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

[Tue May 31 10:53:08.687104 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7534] AH00051: child pid 14348 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

[Tue May 31 10:53:13.692622 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7534] AH00051: child pid 14415 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

websites are giving me a empty response.

I always used mod_ruid2 together with mod_php in order to serve php content as the server owner. When is disable mod_ruid2 mod_php is working fine. Can someone confirm that i 'm not the only one with this problem?

the apache modules i have loaded are:

```
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

And the php modules I have enabled are

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Update:

It appears to be caused by the http2 module i have installed. When i disable http2 it is working fine.